# correcting parsed URLs in java

Tags: java, url, html-parsing

I am creating a HTML parser that gets the HTML from a given URL, finds the navigation menu html, and puts it into a String. The URLs in the HTML that are being copied into the String need part of the URL added (the "www.stackoverflow.com" part). How can I go about finding the existing URLs in the String and adding the missing part to it so that they work.

The URLs in the `String` are of the form:

```
<a href="/qestions/11744851.cfm">
```

and I need to make them in the following form:

```
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com/questions/11744851.cfm">
```

Comment: the URLs in the String are in the form "<a href="/qestions/11744851.cfm">" and i need to make it <a href="www.stackoverflow.com/questions/11744851.cfm">"

Comment: What Java code are you using to read in the website?

Comment: URL page = new URL("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
URLConnection connection = page.openConnection();

then I've tried to replace it with subString.replaceAll("<a href=\"/", "<a href=\"www.stackoverflow.com/");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this regular expression with the `ReplaceAll()` method:

```
str = subString.replaceAll("<a href=\"(.*)\">", "<a href=\"http://www.stackoverflow/$1\">");
```

Answer (score 1):

If the XHTML is valid XML, the easiest way is to parse it as XML and use XPath (for example /body/div/a@href , where /body/div is path to menu section in HTML.
There is also a project called HTMLParser (http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/), you may want to give it a try (according to the page, it has 'link extraction, for crawling through web pages or harvesting email addresses'; but I've never used it, so I can't help much).
If on the other hand the HTML is anything but valid, you may want to use http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/ - it might work, or it might not, on websites we've tried, it did pretty good.

Edit: adding missing part may be done using simple concatenation after finding interesting parts